# Помогите с javascript. Нужно задать изображение из папки

Tags: javascript

Помогите с javascript. В примере 5 изображений подгружаются с интернета, а нужно чтоб с папки на компе. Пробовал "../images/1.jpg", не выходит (js и изображение в разных папках)
var myImg = new Array(
"http://4ert666.moy.su/_ph/5/1/101668975.jpg",
"http://avatar.domik.mobi/files/679-100.jpg",
"http://www.userpic.su/avatar/100x100/10821.gif",
"http://moreavatar.info/mults/mults_bender.jpg"

);
randnm=Math.round(Math.random()*(myImg.length-1));
document.getElementById("TopLine").innerHTML = "<img src='"+myImg[randnm]+"' />";

Comment: Попытайтесь немного подумать, вот это HTML:

    <img src='"+myImg[randnm]+"' />
Он на странице будет у клиента, так как там может быть ресурс который через HTTP недоступен?

Answer (score 1):

Путь к картинки надо указывать относительно html страницы, либо указывать абсолютный путь (пример C:\Users\zhukov\Pictures\qwe.png)